# Sorting a matrix by a vector with correct numeration

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I am looking to sort a matrix by a vector, it's partially working : I have a matrix g (2 column id and nobs) that I sort by the vector id.

My code is this one :

```
 g[order(id),]
```

The sorting is OK however I end up with this result :

```
  id nobs
6 30  932
5 29  711
4 28  475
3 27  338
2 26  586
1 25  463
```

And I am looking to an output this way :

```
  id nobs
1 30  932
2 29  711
3 28  475
4 27  338
5 26  586
6 25  463
```

What is the first column with the numeration 1 to 6  and do I impact that ?

R 3.2.1, Windows 10

Comment: Those are the row numbers of the initial unsorted data frame. See `?rownames()` for possibilities to change them.

Comment: is it a matrix or a dataframe?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Yes, you're right. It's a matrix according to the OP. Makes no difference in this case, though.

Answer (score 1):

The first number of each line is just the name of the row. If you want/need to fix it, you can just use the following (after the ordering):

```
m <- g[order(id),]
rownames(m) <- 1:nrow(g)
```

and it should look the way you want it.

Comment: simply in a one liner `\`rownames<-\`(g[order(id),], 1:nrow(g))`